# Why does BlocProvider.value only works when I cast the variable to it's own type?

Tags: flutter, dart, types, routes, bloc

I'm trying to create a generic function to wrap a screen builder with providers for a List of blocs. This is what I have so far:

```
 class AppRouter {
  final _cartCubit = CartCubit();
  

Route onGenerateRoute(RouteSettings settings) {
    MaterialPageRoute generateRoute(builder, {List blocs}) {
      return MaterialPageRoute(
        settings: settings,
        builder: (blocs ?? []).fold(
          builder,
          (previousValue, bloc) {
            if (bloc is Cubit<Object>)
              return (_) => BlocProvider.value(
                    value: bloc,
                    child: Builder(builder: previousValue),
                  );
            else
              return previousValue;
          },
        ),
      );
    }  

switch (settings.name) {
      case '/':
        return generateRoute((_) => Home(), blocs: [_cartCubit]);
        break;

... }}
```

When I run the code, the BlocBuilders and Listeners in my app can't find the Cubit, so I get the error: `Error: Could not find the correct Provider<CartCubit> above this BlocBuilder<CartCubit, CartState> Widget`. If I pass the value to BlocProvider.value casting bloc like this: `value: bloc as CartCubit`, it works perfectly. It also works perfectly if I replace the "bloc" variable with the _cartCubit variable, even tough "bloc == _cartCubit" evaluates to "true". So I assume that when my List of Cubits is passed as an argument, the CartCubit loses it's type, so it can't be foun by Builders. This happens even when I give the List blocs that is passed as an argument to generateRoute a type, such as `List<Cubit> blocs`.

But when I debug, I can hover over the bloc variable, and it shows the correct type 'CartCubit'. Why is this hapenning? If the bloc variable already has the type "CartCubit", why do I need to cast it? Is there any way to avoid it, since I want to be able to give different Cubits as arguments to generateRoute? Why can't I do something like List, or how can I have the variable not lose it's type when passing it to the List?

Thank you in advance.